# Output html controls - dynamic control name

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to output html controls using xslt, but I need to be able to name the controls so that I can get at them when the form posts back.

I'd like to be able to name the radio button `"action_" + _case_id`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xsl"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Cases>
    <Case>
      <case_id>30</case_id>
    </Case>
  <Cases>
</NewDataSet>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <div class="your_action">
      Your action:<br />
      <input type="radio" name="?" value="No" checked ="true"/> nothing to report<br />
      <input type="radio" name="?" value="Yes" /> memo to follow
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:


```
<input type="radio" name="{concat('action_', /*/*/*/case_id)}"
 value="No" checked ="true"/>
```

In case your xml document changes it may be necessary to substitute the "*" chars above with more detailed location steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="data.xsl"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Cases>
    <Case>
      <case_id>30</case_id>
    </Case>
  <Cases>
</NewDataSet>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="actionid">action_<xsl:value-of select="Cases/Case/case_id"/></xsl:variable>
     <div class="your_action">
      Your action:<br />
      <input type="radio" name="{actionid}" value="No" checked ="true"/> nothing to report<br />
      <input type="radio" name="{actionid}" value="Yes" /> memo to follow
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

NOTE: Not tested. You probably want add a matcher specifically for the Case node not just matching on the root node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix the variable with a $ sign when referencing it:

```
<input type="radio" name="{$actionid}" value="No" checked ="true"/> nothing to report<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset has the nice property that it's a tree, each node can be identified by it's path in the tree. I'd say your best bet is to name the controls that correspond to each XML node in a manner that reflects this:

1. NewDataSet_Cases_Case1_case_id1_rb.
2. NewDataSet_Cases_Case1_case_id2_rb.

You just need a way to get the names of the parent nodes, something like:

```
&lt;xsl:variable name="parent1Name"
              select="name(parent::*)" /&gt;
```